# Packaging issues with barrels in angular 7 library

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-library, ng-packagr

I am trying to create a library with multiple modules in it. My library structure is as below.

[image]

I have multiple modules like common-ui.

**Problem 1**

I have the module and i have index.ts files in each of the folders shown above, and from my public.ts i am doing

```
export * from 'export * from './common-ui';
```

This results in the following error

[image]

Also i see that lib.metadata.json is empty

```
{"__symbolic":"module","version":4,"exports":[{"from":"./node-tree/index"}],"metadata":{},"origins":{},"importAs":"@lib/client"}
```

But if i use barrel file explicitly as below (in all files where barrels are used)

```
export * from 'export * from './common-ui/index';
```

the error goes off and things work fine. **Do i need to specify the barrel file explicitly ? Is there any way around this ?**

**Problem 2**

After the above thing worked (using index), if i use the barrel and import the files as

```
import { CommonUiModule, Node } from '@lib/common';
```

everything works fine. But if i explicitly specify the path as

```
import { CommonUiModule, Node } from '@lib/common/common-ui';
```

It results in the following error

[image: Here]

**Is it happening because of the first error or do we need to add anything special while building the library to access the subfolders as well.** Please help.

My **tsconfig.lib.json** file is as below

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/lib",
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "types": [],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2018"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "annotateForClosureCompiler": true,
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "enableResourceInlining": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is it my eyes or your code shows one too many single quotes in your export line ?

Comment: Your screenshots make it too difficiult for me to read the actual error messages you have.